# Bill Calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just started learning python and i have been trying to learn coding for a few days. I wrote a bill calculation code, but there is a point I don't understand.

When I write a number other than `10`, `15`, `20`, I want the text I wrote in the else part to appear, but this does not work except for `20`. What should I do?

```py
print("\t Welcome to Tip Calculator")

bill = float(input("What was the total bill? $"))

people = int(input("How many people split to bill? "))

tip_percantage = int(input("What percentage tip would you like to give? 10, 15 or 20? "))

tip = bill * tip_percantage / 100

if tip_percantage == 10:
    print("Each people should pay: " + str( (bill + tip) / people) )
    
if tip_percantage == 15:
    print("Each people should pay: " + str( (bill + tip) / people) )
    
if tip_percantage == 20:
    print("Each people should pay: " + str( (bill + tip) / people) )

else:
    print(f"{tip_percantage} is not valid percentage!")
```

Answer (score 2):

You have three separate if statements here. What you're looking for is `elif`. [More here.](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_elif.asp)

```
if tip_percantage == 10: 
    print("Each people should pay: " + str( (bill + tip) / people) )
elif tip_percantage == 15: 
    print("Each people should pay: " + str( (bill + tip) / people) )
elif tip_percantage == 20: 
    print("Each people should pay: " + str( (bill + tip) / people) )
else: 
    print(f"{tip_percantage} is not valid percentage!")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you use `if` multiple times so `else` is attached to last `if tip_percantage == 20`.
so first `if` not True will print anything.

- To Fix this swap last 2 `if's` with `elif`

```
print("\t Welcome to Tip Calculator")

    bill = float(input("What was the total bill? $"))

    people = int(input("How many people split to bill? "))

    tip_percantage = int(input("What percentage tip would you like to give? 10, 15 or 20? "))

    tip = bill * tip_percantage / 100

    if tip_percantage == 10: print("Each people should pay: " + str((bill + tip) / people))

    elif tip_percantage == 15: print("Each people should pay: " + str((bill + tip) / people))

    elif tip_percantage == 20:
        print("Each people should pay: " + str((bill + tip) / people))

    else:
        print(f"{tip_percantage} is not valid percentage!")
```